# Slow and glitchy AirPlay under Mavericks

Tags: macos, airplay

I have a mid-2011 iMac which could AirPlay video beautifully in and out of iTunes to my Apple TV before Mavericks. Now that I've installed OS X Mavericks 10.9 (13A603) I have latency issues. The audio plays fine but video skips a lot, especially when I'm mirroring my display with AirPlay. I tried a wired and wireless connect and both have issues. Is anyone else experiencing this or have a workaround?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have Macbook Air (mid 2011) and just tried to play some video through airplay on the newly bought Apple TV. The performance is really bad. The video is skipping and even moving the mouse pointer on the TV screen is quite painful.

Comment: @kmb Please upvote this question so that it gets more attention and hopefully someone will have a fix.